# overriding standard buttons with lightning components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, button-overrides

I am trying to override a standard "New" button that appears when Case tab is clicked ,so i navigated to new button on the object and i see lightning component bundle is one way to override but when i select the dropdown i dont see my lightning components , is this Beta? or do my lightning component need to implement something ? or below answer in the link is what needs to be implemented for now lightning comp in VF?

[How can I override standard buttons with a custom Lightning page?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/152250/how-can-i-override-)
  standard-buttons-with-a-custom-lightning-page

[image: navigating to override]

[image: New Button on Case Tab]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your component needs to implement `lightning:actionOverride`.
This is only available starting in Summer '17 and you can find the whole documentation [here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_lightning_action_overrides.htm).

Comment: Could you please check this post?
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/302640/opportunity-button-override-for-lightning-experience