# Opportunity button override for lightning experience

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, opportunity, aura

I would like to know why 'Lightning experience override' option is not present in Opportunity Clone button override. I could override the New as well as Edit buttons. But in the case of Clone button, I can see only the 'Salesforce classic override option'. Can anyone throw some light on this? I have implemented `lightning:actionOverride` in my aura component.

Attaching the screenshot.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> we do not have a feature to override the clone button with lightning component on any Object.So,in order to use the clone button you need to create the new button using the lightning component and remove the standard clone button from the pagelayout to achieve your requirement.

This is the response I got from the Salesforce developer forum. Posting this here so that this would be beneficial for others.